# Border-radius on iframe not working on MAC (safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am facing css problem. 
Border radius on  is not working on mac book (Safari).. 
when i try on widows its working well..

Here is my html

```
   <div class="map">
       <div class="map-border">    
          <iframe width="295" height="295" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3160.515465008442!2d-122.40503609999998!3d37.6135611!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x808f77776e3c0101%3A0x78bd162ebe8e8904!2s1699+El+Camino+Real+%23201!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1403695117548">

        </iframe>
   </div>
```

Here is my css code.

```
        .map {
width: 315px;
height: 315px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
border: 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) solid;
-webkit-border-radius: 190px;
-moz-border-radius: 190px;
-ms-border-radius: 190px;
-o-border-radius: 190px;
border-radius: 190px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in; 
z-index: 10;
}
.map .map-border {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 295px;
  border: 10px white solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 190px;
  -moz-border-radius: 190px;
  -ms-border-radius: 190px;
  -o-border-radius: 190px;
  border-radius: 190px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -10;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  }

 iframe {
-webkit-border-radius: 190px;
-moz-border-radius: 190px;
-ms-border-radius: 190px;
-o-border-radius: 190px;
border-radius: 190px;
border: 0; 
display: block;
}
```

Here is the live code. 
http://jsfiddle.net/adnan00733/ju9zL9um/
Note : On windows it will look well. But unfortunately its not working on MAC..

PLEASE HELP. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like there is no solution to this((

Comment: when i click on up vote i receive this message "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" and my vote remove.

Comment: You can only mark as correct, because you don't have enough reputation to upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the best solution I could come up with is:

1. Putting an image on the top of your map. In this case you probably can't access your map.

[image]

2. Putting four images i.e. one on each side of your map. Not the most beautiful solution, but as long as it works...))

(I can cut the image into pieces for you if you want)

Comment: Kholov..
Thanks for your reply .. i use this solution till i get some better solution ..

Comment: You are welcome. I saw a couple question similar to yours at stackOverflow. Doesn't seem like someone has solved it. @adnan00733